# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning after catching a rejected promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Running the following code with Node v8.1.4:

```
testPromise((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});

function testPromise(callback) {
  Promise.reject(new Error('error!'))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('caught');
    callback(err);
  });
}
```

returns the following:

```
caught
(node:72361) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 2): Error: test
(node:72361) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I would have expected an `uncaughtException` to be thrown?
How can I turn this into an uncaught exception?

Comment: Well, you are rethrowing the error in the callback. That causes the promise returned by `.catch()` to be rejected. I don't think you can turn that into an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially throwing inside the catch callback. This is caught and turned into another rejected promise. So you'll get no `uncaughtException`

```
Promise.reject("err")
.catch(err => {
    throw("whoops") //<-- this is caught
})
.catch(err => console.log(err)) // and delivered here -- prints "whoops"
```

One thing to be careful of is asynchronous function that throw. For example this IS an uncaught exception:

```
Promise.reject("err")
   .catch(err => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          throw("whoops")   // <-- really throws this tim
   }, 500)
})
.catch(err => console.log(err)) //<-- never gets caught.
```

Comment: OK. That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. It's just odd in the situation where the returned error is passed up many levels and loses the context of having being generated from a rejected promise. I guess this only causes an issue if you're relying on a  process.on('uncaughtException') handler to do some cleanup (which was my situation). @Mark_M Any thoughts on the best way to approach this?